# Spring boot app not loading in standalone tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple spring boot app in a stand-alone tomcat. I've tried following the reference docs and a few question/answers here but nothing seems to work. When tomcat starts up it deploys the app but completely ignores my Application class so no spring code gets loaded. I am sure it must be something simple I'm missing but...?

Here's the relevant output in the log file:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\dev\servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\bankweb-0.1.war
Feb 15, 2017 4:41:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list o
f JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and
JSP compilation time.
Feb 15, 2017 4:41:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\dev\servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\bankweb-0.1.war has finished in 3,595
 ms
```

I've updated the Application class to extend SpringBootServletInitializer as per the docs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

And in the pom I've changed packaging to war and marked the embedded servlet container as provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.ankle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bankweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.69</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Only thing I can see in your Application class is the overridden `SpringApplicationBuilder configure()` method which I don't have. As a side note you can replace `@Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan` with `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, user error pretty much sums it up. I stripped everything back to remove all the optional spring modules, got it working, then added everything in bit by bit and it worked. I am not really accustomed to this spring boot stuff yet where functionality gets included just because you've configured a library in the pom. Thanks to anyone who took the time to read!